# What's the difference between "much the more" and "much more"?

Tags: difference, articles

for example:
**(1)** *X is much **the** more common than Y*.
I don't understand the role of "*the*" here.
What does "*the*" mean in (1)?

**(2)** *X is much more common than Y*.
What's the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: much the more is not standard and is up there with: I don't know where they are at.

Comment: The first makes you sound like a British person in the 1800s.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is not commonly said, and even though listeners will understand you, they will consider it an incorrect way of speaking.

(2) is correct.

Say:

**Example #2 is *much more common* than example #1.**

However, it is OK to directly compare two things with "much the more", without using "than":

**Of the two examples, #2 is *much the more* common.**

If it helps, try removing "much" from the two sentences and seeing if it makes more sense:

"Of the two examples, #2 is *the* more common." (correct)

"Of the two examples, #2 is *much the* more common." (correct)

and

"Example #2 is the more common than Example #1."  (incorrect)

"Example #2 is much the more common than Example #1." (incorrect)

Comment: What is the difference between "_Of the two examples, #2 is much **the** more common._" and "_Of the two examples, #2 is much more common._"? Thanks.

Comment: They mean exactly the same thing, no difference in meaning.

Comment: Can I put "_the_" before "_much_": "_Of the two examples, #2 is **the** much more common_." ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, "number two is the much more common" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: "Of the two examples, #2 is the much more common." and "#2 is the much more common example" are also both fine.  All of these mean the same thing.

Comment: Please explain your downvote so that the question can be improved.

Comment: I didn't vote "down". I voted "up". P.S.: if you don't put "@user" at the beginning of your comment, this user doesn't see it in their notifications.

Comment: I don't know what user voted down.  The comment wasn't addressed at you (or I would have tagged you!) but meant as a general reminder to explain downvotes on questions and answers.

Answer (score -1):

"X is much the more common than Y" makes sense if it is understood that X and Y are some object or thing, such as a phrase, and that thing is only implied, as in "X is much the more common (phrase) than Y. As such, it means exactly the same as "X is much more common than Y."

However, it's an uncommon usage and would identify the speaker as having intellectual pretensions.

Comment: You may have a peccadillo regarding the phrase, but it has enjoyed consistent use from the mid-19th century through the present in both American and British English.   Based on use-source it clearly does not signal "intellectualism", not is its use exclusively or even mainly academic.  Please support your claim that use would "identify the speaker as having intellectual pretensions" if it is really anything other than a hastily made hip-shot opinion.

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean by "that thing is also implied".  (does "that" refer to "thing X" or "thing Y"?  How is it "implied"?  Please give illustrative use.)

Comment: @BadZen - I already provided an example, where *(phrase)" indicates the word would be left out and implied, rather than explicitly stated. I suggest you do an ngram search on a phrase such as "much the more common". You'll see declining usage since about 1900, and if you examine recent usages you'll see that all of them are in textbooks and other "serious" publications.